# Hi everybody! I would appreciate some help with this DH convention application. It involves a slider-crank mechanism and I'm not sure I did it right

Tags: dh-parameters, theory

[image: DH Frames and Table]

Okay, I'm editing the post and adding some clarifications: I'm considering the slider-crank now as a closed kinematic chain, and for this reason I isolated two different branches. My attempt with the following script is to get a simulation of its motion, but since I've still errors, I think I'm not getting something about the Symbolic Toolbox and about DH convention as well.
Edit 2: I'm attaching the picture of a second solution proposal, this time I get complex numbers on MATLAB.. Now I'm sure I miss something about solving closed kinematic chains. [image: DH Tables and parameters alternative]

```
    clear all
close all
clc
%% Input Parameter (Change k in order to vary end-effector trajectory)
% Conversion factor from centimetres to metres
conv = 0.01;
% Incremental step 
h = 0.1;
% Lenght of crank (link L1) in [m]
l = 5*conv;
k = 2;
% Length of links of mechanism

L1 = 9*l;
L3 = 18*l;
L2 = 6*l;

% Length of virtual links for closed loop equations
%L0 = k*L1;

% Actuator - Costant angular velocity
Theta1 = [0:h:2*pi];
Theta1_ = Theta1 + pi;
beta = asin(L1/L2)*sin(Theta1);


%% Denavit Hartenberg - Forward Kinematic
syms  theta1 d3 theta2 theta3 

% For example T30_1s means transformation matrix from Joint 3 to Joint 0
% for the 1 closed loop (p), if second branch is considered (s)
%%
% Transformation matrix Joint 1 to Joint 0 (workspace)
T10 =  DH(L1,0,0,theta1);

% Transformation matrix Joint 2 to Joint 1
T21 = DH(L2,0,0,theta2);

T20 = T10*T21

T32 = DH(0,pi/2,0,theta3);

T30_p = T20*T32; %this is the first branch of my closed kinematic chain

T30_s = DH(L3,-pi/2,d3,pi/2); % this is the second one, it goes from Joint3 (the prismatic one) to Joint0



%% 

% Closure equation 
eq2 = T30_p(1:3,end) == T30_s(1:3,end)



[Theta2, Theta3, D3] = solve(eq2,[theta2 theta3 d3]);

  angle2 = double(subs(Theta2(1),theta1,Theta1));
  angle3 = double(subs(Theta3(1),theta1,Theta1));
  displ = double(subs(D3(1),theta1,Theta1));

%%

% Joint vector position
J0 = [0 0 0]';
Joint1 = T10(1:3,end);
Joint2 = T21(1:3,end);
Joint3 = T30_s(1:3,end);


% Compute joint trajectory
for i = 1:length(Theta1)
    J1(:,i) = double(subs(Joint1,{theta1 theta2(1)},{Theta1(i) angle2(i)}));
    J2(:,i) = double(subs(Joint2,{theta1 theta2(1) theta3(1)},{Theta1(i) angle2(i) angle3(i)}));
    J3(:,i) = double(subs(Joint3,{d3(1)},{displ(i)}));
   
end
    



%% Movie
figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1])
view(2)
set(gca,'nextplot','replacechildren');
v = VideoWriter('SingleLegFoot.avi');
open(v);
hold on
grid on
for i = 1:length(Theta1)
    clf
    hold on
    grid on
    hold on
    grid on
    axis equal
    xlim([-0.5 1.2]);ylim([-1.6 0.5]);xlabel('X [m]');ylabel('Y [m]')
    title('1 DOF Leg mechanism');
    set(gca,'FontSize',14)
    h12 = plot([J0(1,1),J1(1,i)],[J0(2,1),J1(2,i)],'r','LineWidth',2);
    h13 = plot([J1(1,i),J2(1,i)],[J1(2,i),J2(2,i)],'r','LineWidth',2);
    h14 = plot([J2(1,i),J3(1,i)],[J2(2,i),J3(2,i)],'r','LineWidth',2);

    hold on
    
    h1 = plot(J0(1,:),J0(2,:),'blackv','MarkerSize',10);
    text(J0(1,1)+0.02,J0(2,1),'0');
    h2 = plot(J1(1,i),J1(2,i),'o','MarkerSize',7,'MarkerEdgeColor','black','MarkerFaceColor',[0.7529 0.7529 0.7529]);
    text(J1(1,i)-0.01,J1(2,i)+0.03,'1');
    h3 = plot(J2(1,i),J2(2,i),'o','MarkerSize',7,'MarkerEdgeColor','black','MarkerFaceColor',[0.7529 0.7529 0.7529]);
    text(J2(1,i)+0.02,J2(2,i),'2');
    h4 = plot(J3(1,i),J3(2,i),'blackv','MarkerSize',10);
    text(J3(1,1)+0.02,J3(2,1),'3');
    
    hold off
    frame = getframe(gcf);
    writeVideo(v,frame);
end
close(v);
%% Denavit - Hartenberg Transformation Matrix

function dh = DH(link,a_i,d_i,theta_i)
    dh = [cos(theta_i) -sin(theta_i)*cos(a_i)   sin(theta_i)*sin(a_i)     link*cos(theta_i);
          sin(theta_i)  cos(theta_i)*cos(a_i)   -cos(theta_i)*sin(a_i)     link*sin(theta_i);
               0         sin(a_i)                   cos(a_i)                        d_i;
               0             0                          0                           1       ];
end
```

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: First of all I would like to know if my DH table is correct

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot going on here, and it's not specific what your question is as jsotola mentions.

First, you are putting the output of a `solve` function into `Theta2`, but then you're using `THETA2` as inputs to subsequent `subs` functions. Matlab is case-sensitive; those are two **different** terms.

Second, assuming you're using symbolic variables (based on your error) you can't, as the error states, mix symbolic and doubles. This is probably happening in your line `eq2 = T_end(1:3,end) == [0;0;0];` which instead needs to be `eq2 = T_end(1:3,end) == sym([0;0;0]);` to work.

Third, I can't see where any of your stuff is actually defined - your Theta1, THETA3, etc.

Fourth, you're using a `DH` function but that's not a built-in Matlab function.

Put everything you're trying to do in a script, start that script with the `clear` or `clear all` command, and try running as a saved script. Any errors you get will give you line numbers, pointing you to exactly where the problem is. If you still have trouble, please post *the entire script* so we can follow along with your variable declarations, etc.

Comment: Thank you both! I'll post my entire script, I'm working on it in order to be clear what my problem is next time.

Comment: Just edited my post, hope it's better now

Comment: @smarzo - When I run your code, I get the error where you're substituting the numeric values for theta1 in the Theta2 expression. The issue is that your Theta2 expression is just `z`, so the output is a vector of `z`, and then you're trying to convert that to a numeric value when there is no numeric value for z.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too. And this makes me think that the equations are wrong!